# How to convert utf-8 characters to "normal" characters in string in python3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have raw data that looks like this:

> 25023,Zwerg+M%C3%BCtze,0,1,986,3780
> 25871,red+earth,0,1,38,8349
> 25931,K4m%21k4z3,90,1,1539,2530

It is saved as a .txt file: https://de205.die-staemme.de/map/player.txt

The "characters" starting with % are unicode, as far as I can tell.

I found the following table about it: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Here is my code so far:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url,pfad + "player.txt")

f = open(pfad + "player.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
raw = raw.split("\n")
f.close()
```

Python does not convert the %-characters. They are read as if they were seperate characters.

Is there a way to convert these characters without calling .replace like 200 times?

Thank you very much in advance for help and/or useful hints!

Comment: You want https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The %s are URL-encoding; use `urllib.parse.unquote` to decode the string.

```
>>> raw = """25023,Zwerg+M%C3%BCtze,0,1,986,3780
... 25871,red+earth,0,1,38,8349
... 25931,K4m%21k4z3,90,1,1539,2530"""
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> print(urllib.parse.unquote(raw))
25023,Zwerg+Mütze,0,1,986,3780
25871,red+earth,0,1,38,8349
25931,K4m!k4z3,90,1,1539,2530
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much!